# One session for Tabular Editor CLI

Tags: powerbi, command-line-interface, powershell-core, tabular-editor

I am automating a deployment (for now to be run by a dev on local machine) which migrates datasets from one Power BI workspace to another.
I am using the Tabular Editor CLI to save the bim file, modify it and then deploy it to the new workspace using calls like the following in powershell scripts

```
Start-Process -FilePath $tabularEditorPath -Wait -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "$xmlaSourceEndpoint $datasetId -B $bimFilePath -V -W"

Start-Process -FilePath $tabularEditorPath -Wait -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "$bimFilePath -D $xmlaTargetEndpoint `"$datasetName`" -O -P -V -W"
```

The problem is that each time each of these commands run I am prompted to authenticate and this happens for each dataset being migrated so 2x authentication per dataset!

Is there no way to persist the session and only require one authentication?

Comment: Is service principal authentication an option? If so, I can provide an answer that covers that.

Comment: Thanks yes... im the end I went with that and it worked. so issue resolved